# Как сгруппировать данные агрегатные функ

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Есть таблица tbl_Regist:

```
| ID | CODE   | VAL       |
+----+--------+-----------+
| 95 | numVz  | 06        |
| 95 | prevVz | 84605898  |
| 95 | ndatVz | 10.10.10  |
| 95 | numVz  | 06        |
| 95 | prevVz | 14666641  |
| 95 | ndatVz | 11.11.11  |
| 95 | numVz  | 06        |
| 95 | prevVz | 84605898  |
| 95 | ndatVz | 12.12.12  |
```

Мне нужно получить данные в таком ввиде:

```
| ID | numVz | prevVz   | ndatVz   | 
+----|-------+----------+----------+
| 95 | 06    | 84605898 | 10.10.10 |   
| 95 | 06    | 14666641 | 11.11.11 |
| 95 | 06    | 84605898 | 12.12.12 |
```

**Мой запрос:**

```
select 
      t.ID,
      max(case when t.code = 'numVz'  then t.val end) as numVz
     ,max(case when t.code = 'prevVz' then t.val end) as prevVz
     ,max(case when t.code = 'ndatVz' then t.val end) as ndatVz
from tbl_Regist t
where t.ID = 95
group by t.ID   

| ID | numVz | prevVz   | ndatVz   | 
+----|-------+----------+----------+
| 95 | 06    | 84605898 | 12.12.12 |
```

Возвращает только одну строку

Comment: А как понять что `14666641` должен группироваться именно с `11.11.11`, а не с `12.12.12`?

Comment: Или не с `10.10.10`? У вас в данных явно не хватает одной колонки. Вы её забыли указать или её нету?

Answer (score 0):

```
select r.ID,
       max(case when r.code = 'numVz'  then r.val end) as numVz,
       max(case when r.code = 'prevVz' then r.val end) as prevVz,
       max(case when r.code = 'ndatVz' then r.val end) as ndatVz
from (select r.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id, code order by <ordering column>) as seqnum
      from tbl_Regist r
     ) r
where r.ID = 95
group by r.ID, seqnum;
```

Comment: Вот как раз `<ordering column>` в вопросе нет, из-за чего на него сложно ответить.

Comment: @default locale, в качестве <ordering column> брал ID

Comment: Тогда имейте ввиду, что для записей с одинаковым ID группировка будет более или менее случайной. Если сейчас `14666641` совпал с  `11.11.11` , то в следующий раз он может попасть в группу с `10.10.10`. Если порядок для Вас важен, то нужно понять как сортировать/группировать записи с одинаковым ID. Если порядок не важен, то все ОК, хотя лучше было бы это сразу указать в вопросе.

Comment: @default locale,  чтобы решить эту проблему , для порядка создал одно поле

Comment: Какое поле вы создали? Если `seqnum`, то оно имеет случайный порядок, как  вам уже @defaultlocale комментарием выше написал. В текушем виде ваш ответ не отвечает на ваш собственный вопрос.